# how to declare a COOKIE LESS session variable in c#, only!

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser-cache

well i mean, that as u will see in my posts, i am getting problems because of caches

so i think cookie less try out

how to declare a cookie less session variable without making the whole website cookie less

meaning,

- website should be cookieless=FALSE
- vairable cookie less true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but if I parsed the question right, here are a few things that may be useful:

- The values stored in the session state object are **not** stored in cookies -- the only cookie sent to the browser is a session identifier, which will tell the server which session state it should fetch when responding to subsequent requests.  The actual session state data is stored on the server.
- If your goal here is to prevent the session cookie from being sent to the browser at all, but still allow sessions to work, you can enable cookieless sessions.  You can read more about that, the pros and cons as well as how to do it, on the [Cookieless ASP.NET page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).